# Prove that these graphs intersect themselves at e and 1/e

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was playing around with graphs on Desmos, and came across the graphs below. Obviously both graphs must have a part that is just y = x, but they also have a separate part, it seems that the graphs intersect themselves at e and 1/e, but I haven't been able to prove this and wondered if anyone could help.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The curved part of the graph of $x^y=y^x$ is given parametrically by $x=t^{1/(t-1)}$, $y=t^{t/(t-1)}$.

Comment: Now, show that as $t\to1$, $x\to e$ and $y\to e$.

Answer (score 2):

## Preface

Let's use a limit $\displaystyle{t \to 1}$ of $y=tx$ to take advantage of the intersections lying on $x=y$

## Intersection $\bf x=y$ and $\bf x^y=y^x$

***substitute y=tx into x^y=y^x***

$x^{tx}=(tx)^x$

***solve for x***

$x^t=tx$

$x^{t-1}=t$

$x=t^{\frac{1}{t-1}}$

***calculate limit $t\to1$ where we approach x = y***

$\displaystyle{x=\lim_{t \to 1}t^{\frac{1}{t-1}}}$

***let r=t-1***

$\displaystyle{=\lim_{r \to 0}(r+1)^{\frac{1}{r}}}$

$\boxed{x=e}$

## Intersection $\bf x=y$ and $\bf x^x=y^y$

***substitute y=tx into x^x=y^y***

$x^{x}=(tx)^{tx}$

***solve for x***

$x=(tx)^t$

$x=t^t * x^t$

$x^{1-t}=t^t$

$x=t^{\frac{t}{1-t}}$

***calculate limit $t\to1$ where we approach x = y***

$\displaystyle{x=\lim_{t \to 1} t^{\frac{t}{1-t}} }$

***let r=1-t***

$\displaystyle{=\lim_{r \to 0}(1-r)^{\frac{1}{r}}}$

$\boxed{x=e^{-1}}$